# Is this machine learning + matrix manipulation question on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, r, machine-learning

I just put a bounty on [Calculating Linear Discriminant Analysis Coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308872/calculating-linear-discriminant-analysis-coefficients) before seeing the ML discussions on Meta, so I apologize for not asking about this beforehand. I'll be sure to make a future note of what comes out of this discussion.

The question, in short, is asking about how to manually calculate the coefficients outputted by a machine learning algorithm using matrices. In addition, `R` code is a substantial part of this, and it looks like the algorithm itself involves a lot of advanced linear algebra which I am not familiar with (singular value decomposition). Therefore, I don't consider this question to be in the category described in [As machine learning gets more programming-oriented, should we get more programming oriented?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/as-machine-learning-gets-more-programming-oriented-should-we-get-more-programmi).

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: IMHO, it is perfectly on topic.

Comment: I agree with @Tim, your Q is perfectly on topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just containing code doesn't make it off topic; the question seems to me to be firmly on-topic.

In any case, in relation to programming questions (which I don't think this one actually is), the [help/on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here

So even if it were more of a programming-related question than it looks at first read, I think this phrase would mean it would be on topic.